# v-for="key in columns" was unable to built by webpack in Vue?

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I plan to build `Vue` demo component into my project using `webpack`, but I get the below error, Would you please tell me what's happened please?

```
ERROR in ./~/babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&plugins[]=transform-runtime&comments=false!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/pms/dashboard.vue
Module build failed: SyntaxError: D:/WorkSpace/YongTai/src/components/pms/dashboard.vue: Unexpected token (2:0)
  <  th v-for="key in columns"
    at Parser.pp.raise (D:\WorkSpace\YongTai\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\location.js:22:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (D:\WorkSpace\YongTai\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\util.js:89:8)
```

My `vue` code include the below code line:

```
script type="text/x-template" id="grid-template">
< table>< t head> < tr>< t h v-for="key in columns"
```

Comment: remove spaces inside `< table` , `< t h` etc

Comment: There is no spaces in my code, To show the code in stackoverflow, I had to add some spaces.

Comment: It just hit me! you should be using `<template>` tag instead of `<script type= ... ` in vue files.

Answer (score 0):

Have You got right webpack config file with babel builder and support for vue components in separate files?

my `webpack.config.js`

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  // the main entry of our app
  entry: ['./src/index.js', './src/auth/index.js'],
  // output configuration
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build/',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      // process *.vue files using vue-loader
      { test: /\.vue$/, loader: 'vue' },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html' },
      // process *.js files using babel-loader
      // the exclude pattern is important so that we don't
      // apply babel transform to all the dependencies!
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/ }
    ]
  },
  babel: {
    presets: ['es2015'],
    plugins: ['transform-runtime']
  },
}
```

in vue.js good choice for tables is to use [vue-tables](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables)